# Is there any way to override version on running mvn clean install?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I've a maven project with pom file as below:

```
<groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

This project is used by another one but with a lower version `<version>2.0.1</version>`:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- other -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't want to change `version` in the first pom to `2.0.1` so I wonder if there is any way to override the version on running `mvn clean install` under the first project?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It sounds this artifact `my-artifact` has already been released before so there should be existing a tag in the version control. The simplest way is to checkout that state and do simply a `mvn install` on it.

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you much! I've posted your comment as correct answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It sounds this artifact my-artifact has already been released before so there should be existing a tag in the version control. The simplest way is to checkout that state and do simply a mvn install on it.

Thank @khmarbaise for your comment! You let me know how to get the artifact with correct content for version 2.0.1

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to replace the version property `2.0.1` in the second project with a Maven property (e.g. `my-artifact.version`), which defaults to 2.0.1. On the command line you can build this project and override the introduced property with the snapshot version of `my-artifact`:

```
cd other-project
mvn clean install -Dmy-artifact.version=2.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

This is how the second project should look like:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <my-artifact.version>2.0.1</my-arfifact.version>
    ...
  </properties>
  ...
  <dependendies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
      <version><${my-artifact.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Neither `mvn clean install -Dmy-artifact.version=2.0.2-SNAPSHOT` nor `mvn clean install -Dmy.group.id:my-artifact.version=2.0.2-SNAPSHOT` work for me. It gives me the error `Could not resolve dependencies...`. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Did you install the artifacts of `com.group.id:my-artifact:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT` in your local Maven repository? I'm surprised that it did not work for you. I use this pattern often.

Comment: I used `mvn clean install -Dmy-artifact.version=2.0.2-SNAPSHOT` on the second one but no luck, maven still got version `2.0.1`

Comment: I edited my answer which shows you, how my suggestion should look like. I can't imagine that it does not work this way.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to say that I don't want to change any pom file. However, your way is very good. I haven't ever known before. I will remember to use it later. +1 for it :D. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be helpful: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/update-versions-mojo.html

That's is the only way that I know to change automatically the version of a set of poms

Comment: Thank for your answer! But it seems to update `the version numbers` that I don't want. In addition, it seems that it's immpossible to set version to lower number

Comment: @TuanDang You can set the versions to whatever you like with supplemental command line arguments.